# Creating R Markdown htmls by looping

Tags: r, loops, r-markdown

I have a large report that I am running through R Markdown. The report has a data frame. At the beginning of the script, the data frame is filtered. After that, it does lots of manipulation and interpretation.

Currently, I change what I filter for and knit each report individually. I want to automate this process so that I can provide a vector of terms to filter with and the reports are generated.

Here is an example:

```
---
title: "Create markdown htmls with loop"
author: "Nathan Roe"
date: "2/17/2022"
output: html_document
---
```

```
library(dplyr)
```

```
my_df <- data.frame(my_letters = letters[1:5], my_numbers = 1:5)
```

```
my_df %>% filter(my_letters == "a")
```

I want to generate reports for a, b, c, d, and e. Currently, I have to go in and change what is being filtered for. As shown in the example above, I am filtering for "a". After that, I would have to change it to filter for "b", and so on. Is there a way to automate this, so that I provide a vector a, b, c, d, and e and reports are generated based on those filters and htmls are generated using the letter as the title. For example, I provide `my_letters <- letters[1:5]` and the script creates a.html, b.html, c.html, d.html, and e.html.

It seems similar to this, https://community.rstudio.com/t/loop-for-output-files/79716, but this example is poorly explained, if it does even answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you mention gives all the elements to generate a [parametrized report](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/parameterized-reports.html#parameterized-reports).

On your example, you could [knit with custom parameters](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/params-knit.html#knit-with-custom-parameters) using `rmarkdown::render`.

markdown file : `test.Rmd`

````
---
title: "Create markdown htmls with loop"
author: "Nathan Roe"
date: "2/17/2022"
output: html_document
params: 
  letter: 'a'
---


# `r paste('Processing letter ',letter)`

```{r}
letter
```
````

`html` file generation with loop :

```
for (letter in letters[1:5] ) {
  rmarkdown::render(input = 'test.Rmd',
                    output_file = paste0(letter,".html"), 
                    params = list(letter = letter))
}
```

[image]
...